# ASP .NET 5 (MVC6) External Forms Authentication

Tags: forms-authentication, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, owin-middleware

I'm currently investigating an elegant solution to this problem, but I wanted to get this question out here in order to get any advice/suggestions/answers to this problem.

I am working with an authentication system (forms authentication) that the client uses for authentication.

Current Steps:

1. Redirect to URL for forms authentication.
2. Enter Username/Password
3. Get back form data.  Specifically: Context.Request.Form["Token"]

I am able to perform all of these steps.  I am trying to think of the right path to get the middleware to take care of this problem.  I'm currently wondering if I could simply use the Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.Cookies to solve this problem.  With this approach, I would implement my own ICookieManager to look at the Form data.

Advice/Suggestions/Answers?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I came up with my own answer to this question, so I wanted to share.

As I said, I am working with a forms authentication system.  Part of the forms data is a 'Token' value.  My solution involved two parts:

1. I created a middleware component to intercept form data, look for a 'Token' value in the forms data, and write that to a cookie.
2. I used Microsoft's Cookie authentication middleware implementation, but I had to override one of the options, TicketDataFormat.  Their implementation expects a serialized/encrypted ClaimsIdentity.  My token was not that, so I had to implement my own thing to create a ClaimsIdentity based off the token.

I'll be happy to share more detail if anyone is interested, but that is the jist of my solution.

Comment: Would be great if you share the details please, cause I'm in the same situation and don't know how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a specific advice for you.

However now it's available quite good official documentation:
[ASP.NET 5 Security](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/security/index.html)

There you can find more information, including [Authentication in ASP.NET 5](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/security/authentication/index.html)

I hope it will help you.